# What does Erlang's export syntax /x mean? Why the slash and then a number?

Tags: erlang

```
-export([consult/1,
         dump/2, 
         first/1, 
         for/3,
         is_prefix/2).
```

I'm reading documentation and confused with syntax above. What's the meaning of `/1`, `/2`, `/3` in the list above?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`/1, /2, /3` etc are referred to as the ["Arity"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) of the function, Arity meaning the number of arguments accepted by that function.

In Erlang, two functions of with the same name but with different arity are two different functions, and as such are each exported explicitly. To quote the [Erlang documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) is says:

> A function is uniquely defined by the module name, function name, and *arity*.

For example, if you have two functions:

```
do_something() -> does_something().

do_something(SomeArg) -> some_something_else(SomeArg).
```

And at the top of your module, you had only

```
-export([do_something/0]).
```

Then only the do_something with zero arguments would be exported (that is, accessible from other modules in the system).

Comment: thank you! If I have 3 functions of the same name but with different set of parameters (2,3,4), when I export /4 - does that mean that functions with lower arity will be exported as well?

Comment: It does not, actually. You have to export each version of the function separately. So if you wanted to export all versions of that function (with arities 2,3 and 4), you'd have to do
`-export([function/2,function/3,function/4]).`

Comment: The best thing about this is that you can create a helper function (for example a recursive one) and a wrapper (for example without the recursion variable) with the same name, and then just export the wrapper. A minor convenience maybe, but useful nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

It is the function signature.

`consult/1` means the function named `consult` accepts an argument. `dump/2` means the function `dump` accepts two arguments.

Consult the [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/functions.html) for more info